# Using System.Type, what is the life expectancy of the GUID property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.5

I am using .Net 4.5:  When I run Assembly.GetTypes(), I get an array of System.Type.  System.Type has a GUID property.  I have noticed that, if I stop and restart my application, and even if I change something about a class before recompiling, I still get the same GUID value for the class.  Would this ever change and if so, why?

Comment: I see and I agree.  Thanks.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate.  However, as a side note, if you change the ***name*** of the class, you'll notice that the generated guid also changes.  The guid isn't tied to the contents of the class, only the fully qualified name of the type.